# VBA Excel loop through all days in a year

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA:

How do I loop through all days in a given date range?

'2013-01-01' to '2013-01-03' should give:

```
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
```

Comment: How about some more context for this question?  Otherwise, you'll either get no answers, or answers that don't suit what you are trying to do, since we all have to guess.

Comment: It is the same way you would loop through all the days in a given year in any programming language?   Unless there is something else you are not telling us

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should at least show you how to get started with what you're trying to do:

```
  Sub test()

  Dim StartDate As Date
  Dim EndDate As Date
  Dim DateLooper As Date

  StartDate = #1/1/2013#
  EndDate = #12/31/2013#

  For DateLooper = StartDate To EndDate
     MsgBox (DateLooper)
  Next DateLooper

  End Sub
```

Comment: it is possible to use this with ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=DateLooper  I want to save a template ,multiple times so don't have to individually name them with the date.